# The box for editing a user's "About Me" looks different across different browsers

Tags: bug, profile-page

Across different browsers, the box for editing a user's "About Me" looks different.

It seems to look the most correct in Google Chrome.

[image: Chrome]

The text is separated into paragraphs, and the caret is at the top.

However, in Firefox, the text has no paragraphs.

[image: Firefox]

The text is all in one long paragraph.

Edge looks similar to Chrome, but the caret is at the wrong position.

[image: Edge]

I have checked and ensured that I am using the latest version of all browsers.

Firefox 49.0.2
Edge 38.14393.0.0
Chrome 54.0.2840.87

Comment: Try to remove the class of the textarea in Firefox, does this make it appear fine? If so, the bug is in the CSS somewhere, otherwise it's either something on your end (e.g. userscript/extension etc) or bug in Firefox itself, nothing SE can or should fix.

Comment: Any chance of a user link? My first hunch is that  this is a CR/LF/CRLF issue, possibly with the data having been copy/pasted? I'm speculating entirely here, and happy to be entirely wrong - but would be easier to check with a link

Comment: ooh, you mean the placeholder text; my bad... looking now

Comment: What you are describing *seems* in both cases to be simply how those browsers handles `<textarea placeholder="...">`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fsu8gyp0/ - but I'll see what  the options are. To be fair, it looks like multi-line placeholders aren't meant to be used: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7189563/23354

Comment: I'm adding a tweak to at least avoid the problem of wordsandsentencesjoiningtogetherwithoutspaces; I'm inclined to leave the rest of the placeholder up to the browser, though